# What makes this string addition starting with a '+' a valid statement?

Tags: c++, string, syntax, operator-overloading

I had a copy/paste error in my code and ended up with a line that looked like:
`myString = otherString; + "?" + anotherString;`

The code after the first semicolon wasn't issuing any errors or warnings.  Using an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) to double check my environment, I created this quick example that also compiles and runs:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string sText("Hello World");
    std::string sMore(" again");

    + "???" + sText + sMore; //No warning, no error

    cout << sText; //output "Hello World" as expected

    + 4; //Warning has no effect
    + sMore; //error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand type is ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’)


    return 0;
}
```

So what is the beginning + doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal strings (like e.g. `"???"`) are really arrays of characters. And as all other arrays they decay to pointers to themselves. And this is what happens here, the expression `+ "???"` applies the unary `+` operator on the pointer to the first element of the string.

This results in another pointer (to a character) that is equal to the first, and which can then be used to add to `std::string` objects.

The same thing happens for other literals, like numbers, which is why `+4` is valid as well.

But there's no unary `+` operator defined for `std::string` which is why you get an error for `+sMore`.

Comment: Ok, great.  'Unary +' is what I was forgetting about.  I knew the string literal wasn't the same as a std::string.  And I assume that there is no warning on that line because calling operator+ is "having an effect" even tho the value isn't stored.

Comment: [More information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) on unary + operator.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, string literal is an array of characters. When you pass an array as operand to unary operator +, the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to first element (which is of type `const char`). This implicit conversion is called decaying.

The result of unary operator + is the operand after the conversion i.e. the pointer to the first element of the string literal in this case.

The following binary operator + invokes the overloaded operator that takes a pointer to a character as one operand, and a `std::string` object as the other.

For integers, operator + behaves the same, except instead of array-to-pointer decay, there is integral promotion. `int` is not promoted, but all types smaller than `int` are. For `std::string`, there is no overload for unary +, hence the error.

---

> And I assume that there is no warning on that line because calling operator+ is "having an effect" even tho the value isn't stored.

Lack of effect is only a reason to warn about if the result of the operation is discarded. In the string case, the result is used as an operand of the binary operator, so there is no reason to warn about lack of effect.

Now, the result of the binary operation is discraded, and has no effect either, but it is practically impossible for the compiler to analyse all possible code paths for "effects", and it doesn't attempt to do so. The compiler is kind enough to check for primitive operations on pointers, but it probably won't bother analysing function calls (operator overloads for classes are functions).